# Batch File with For Loop outputs empty txt

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, is-empty

I'm trying to run a benchmark on a number of *.exe's in different SubDirs in a folder, then have a txt created with a filename like *.benchmark.txt for each benchmark console output on the individual exes. My output file is blank every time though.  The txt files are created correctly, just nothing is written inside them.  It works with no problems when running them individually

```
    FOR /r %%I in (*.exe) DO (
        START /wait %%I --benchmark > %%~nI.benchmark.txt
    )
```

I've tried > or >> to append, but neither work

Comment: Remove the `start /wait` and directly call the executable. You are redirecting the output of the `start` command, not the output of the executable file.

Comment: @MCND Wouldn't the verbs invoke or run be better than call, as call is a different thing in batch?

Comment: @LotPings, Thank you, I agree with you. `launch | run | invoke | start | call` are usually used, but context matters. Microsoft [uses](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx) the expression *"Command-line tools must be run at the prompt of the Cmd.exe command interpreter"* so I will try to adhere to this term.

Comment: removing start did the trick.  I appreciate the help